# How does 'event' works?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm studying SystemVerilog [event data types](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/data_types4.html#event_data_types). But I can't understanda
the simulation results.

How does event works in SystemVerilog?

## UPDATE

```
1 module events();
  2 // Declare a new event called ack
  3 event ack; 
  4 // Declare done as alias to ack 
  5 event done = ack; 
  6 // Event variable with no synchronization object
  7 event empty = null; 



  9 initial begin
 10    #1  -> ack;
 11    #1  -> empty;
 12    #1  -> done;
 13    #1  $finish;
 14 end
 15 
 16 always @ (ack)
 17 begin
 18   $display("ack event emitted");
 19 end
 20 
 21 always @ (done)
 22 begin
 23   $display("done event emitted");
 24 end
 25 
 26 /*
 27 always @ (empty)
 28 begin
 29   $display("empty event emitted");
 30 end
 31 */
 32 
 33 endmodule
```

How does it show as following?

```
 ack event emitted
 done event emitted
ack event emitted <== I don't understand here Why does it happens?
 done event emitted
```

I think that it should be like this.

```
 ack event emitted

 done event emitted

 done event emitted
```

Comment: At which point you are not able to understand and did you tried any example?

Comment: @Emman I confused the print order.

Comment: if it is only the print order then current answer by Bartels is correct, and if you need more on events i.e for the question "How events work?" better ask separate question.

Comment: @Emman     it just run #1  -> ack;  11    #1  -> empty;  12    #1  -> done; then this sequence is to be like this "ack event emitted" ->

" done event emitted" ->

" done event emitted"  . I think.

Comment: When one event variable is assigned to another (event done = ack); , the two (ack,done) become merged.Thus, executing -> on either event variable affects processes waiting on either event variable. For more detailed answer ask a question seperately here I could not answer since the question is on hold.

Comment: @Emman I get it Thanks  a lot. it's very funny that what if I assign like this 

  event ack; 
  event done = ack; 
  event ack = done;  then is this same thing ?  event ack; 
  event done = ack;

Comment: From my understanding the compiler wont allow you to do that circularly(ie. assigning both(ack=done and done=ack)), events are quiet interesting in fact it has limitation with respect to Active and Inactive queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused about why the events are printed multiple times? Have a look at line5:

```
event done = ack;
```

Now ack and done are synonymous with each other, whenever one event is triggered the other is as well, since each is triggered once you get 4 printouts.

Comment: did you mean that if triggered done or ack then these are same events?

Comment: Triggering one will trigger the other when they're set equal.